# C# - MongoDB ChangeStream Check if specify property changed

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to watch for changes for a specific field in collection using C#.

So far I've being able to watch for any changes in document.

How can I check if a specific field was changed?

```cs
internal class CollectionWatcherService
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _mongoDatabase;
    private readonly ILogger<CollectionWatcherService> _logger;

    public CollectionWatcherService(IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase, ILogger<CollectionWatcherService> logger)
    {
        _mongoDatabase = mongoDatabase;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Watch(string collectionName, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
            var pipeline = CreatePipeline(collectionName);
            var options = CreateCursorOptions();
            using var cursor = await CreateWatcherCursor(collection, pipeline, options, cancellationToken);
            while (await ShouldContinueWatching(cursor, cancellationToken))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Waiting for changes: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                var batch = cursor.Current;
                foreach (var documentChange in batch)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Changed");
                }
            };
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<bool> ShouldContinueWatching(IChangeStreamCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>> cursor,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && await cursor.MoveNextAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private static ChangeStreamOptions CreateCursorOptions()
    {
        return new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };
    }

    private static PipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>, ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>
        CreatePipeline(string collectionName)
    {
        return new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()
            .Match(Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter
                .And(
                    Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter.Eq((document => document.OperationType), ChangeStreamOperationType.Update),
                    Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter.Eq((document => document.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName), collectionName)
                )
        );
    }

    private static Task<IChangeStreamCursor<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>> CreateWatcherCursor(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, PipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>, ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>> pipeline, ChangeStreamOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return collection
            .WatchAsync(pipeline, options, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The field that I need to check for changes is **status**

I've tried to add the following code to the and statement, but the code it's throwing an exception saying

> Expression not supported: document.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields.

```cs
 Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter.AnyStringIn((document => document.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields.Names), "status")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind

I've just figured out.

```cs
    private static PipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>, ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>
        CreatePipeline(string collectionName)
    {
        return new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()
            .Match(Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter
                .And(
                    Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter.Eq((document => document.OperationType), ChangeStreamOperationType.Update),
                    Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter.Eq((document => document.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName), collectionName),
                    Builders<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>.Filter.Exists("updateDescription.updatedFields.status")
                )
        );
    }
```